# Remove Legend from CartoDB Layer

Tags: jquery, maps, legend, layer, cartodb

I am trying to remove the legend associated with the current CartoDB generated map and replace it with a legend from a map generated when the user selects a radio button. My code is as follows:

```
function showMap(radioButton, currentLayer, currentMap, mapUrl) {

            if (radioButton.checked == true) {
                if (currentMap.viz != null) {
                    var vis = currentMap.viz;
                    vis.legends.getLegendByIndex(0).remove();
                }

                cartodb.createLayer(currentMap, mapUrl)
                .addTo(currentMap)

                .on('done', function(layer) {       
                    //do stuff
                    currentLayer=layer

                    .on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
                        console.log(e, latlng, pos, data);
                    })  
                })

                .on('error', function(err) {
                    alert("some error occurred: " + err);
                }); 
            } <!--end function-->
            else {
                currentLayer.hide();
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.